# Meaning of Elliptic Irregular Primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, formal-groups

The Bernoulli numbers are defined by the equation 
$$
\frac{t}{e^t-1}=\sum_k b_k \frac{t^k}{k!}.
$$ 
A prime number $p$ is irregular if it divides the numerator of one of the even Bernoulli numbers up to $(p-3)$, and the irregular primes are exactly those $p$-s for which $p$ divides the size of the class group $\mathcal{Cl}(\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p])$.

Noting that $e^t-1$ is exactly the isomorphism from the formal additive group to the formal moltiplicative group over $\mathbb{Q}$, we can define the elliptic Bernoulli numbers as follows:

Given an elliptic curve $y^2 = x^3 + Ax +B$, let $\log_E(t)$ denote the logarithm of the formal group law associated with $E$, and let $\exp_E(t)$ denote the inverse power series. Then $\exp_E(t)=t + O(t^2)$ and so $\frac{t}{\exp_E(t)}:=\sum b_k^E \frac{t^k}{k!}$ is a power series starting with $1$.

Lets call the numbers $b_k^E$ the "elliptic Bernoulli numbers", just because I don't know what is their official name, if they even have one. 
Call a prime number $p$ E-irregular, if it divides a numerator of one of the numbers $b_k^E$ for $k<p-1$ (or any other reasonable condition of this flavor.)

Question: can we characterize the elliptic irregular primes as the primies dividing the size of some group associated with $E$, such as $\mathcal{CL}(\mathbb{Q}(E[p]))$ or the Selmer group of $E$ or... anything else?

Comment: These are sometimes called Hurwitz-Bernoulli numbers, and have been studied by Katz (and others)..http://doi.org/10.1007/BF02547966 Brief mention of the formal group law (with various useful formulas) is given in this preprint. http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.6125

Comment: Cool thanks. But you know anything about their irregular primes? I couldn't find it in any of them.